# Quickly change css attributes values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have sample code:

```
<div></div>
<button>
Go
</button>

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

var bgs = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black'];
$('button').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < bgs.length; i++) {
    $('div').css('background-color', bgs[i]);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e4jhwtyc/2/

What I want to achieve is that when users click the Go button, users will be able to see the background very quickly changing from red, blue, yellow, green, and then black.
But what I got was just black color when the Go button was clicked.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some timeout to see change in color otherwise it will happen too quickly.

```
var bgs = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black'];
$('button').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < bgs.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('div').css('background-color','').css('background-color', bgs[i]);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()` to change color on some period of time (0.3s for example) otherwise it will change instantly with your code. And when it reaches last element of array you can `clearInterval()` and reset counter `i`

```js
var bgs = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black'];

var i = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < bgs.length) {
      $('div').css('background-color', bgs[i++]);
    } else {
      clearInterval(x);
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 300)
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>
  Go
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time there is a click event the for ends at black color. So it gets black!!!. The for is to fast if you compare that with browser rendering so the other colors don't get rendered.
Try the setTimeout() function with a different offset for each color

Answer (score 0):

This version does not deal with "setTimeout" and "setInterval"

```js
var bgs = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'black'];
function *getBgs(){
  for(let v of bgs) {
    yield v;
  }
}

$('button').click(function() {
  let iter = getBgs();
  let $div = $('div');
  var delay = 150;
  var prev = 0;
  (function nextColor(){
    requestAnimationFrame(function(t){
      if(prev && t - prev < delay) {
        return nextColor();
      }
      prev = t;
      let next = iter.next();
      if(next.done) return;
      $div.css('background-color', next.value);
      nextColor();
    });
  })();
  
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>
  Go
</button>
```